# Javascript / JQuery Set Cookie on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I would appreciate some orientation in the following issue.

I want to set a cookie when a page loads. The cookie value should taken from a `div data-myifo` attribute within the HTML code.

My current code looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id=someid data-myinfo="yyyyy">Hello World</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function set_cookie (cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
      if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
      expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
      document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                       + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString() 
                       + "; path=/";
}

function get_atribute () {
    var myinfo = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("data-myinfo");
    set_cookie ("My_Cookie", myinfo);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    get_atribute ();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried running the function `get_atribute ()` using a `onclick="get_atribute ()"` and that way it works but not on page load or after.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have not included jquery library file.  Due to this your document.ready function is not executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use jQuery here

Could just use:

```
(function() {
    get_attribute();
})();
```